# How to determine that my iOS app is running in DEBUG mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compilation

The code :

```
#if DEBUG
    let iAmInDebugMode = true
#else
    let iAmInDebugMode = false
#endif
```

The project settings :

[image]

The scheme settings :

[image]

The result :

```
println(iAmInDebugMode) // false
```

Why ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I added answer, you need to set flag in Other_swift_flags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In swift it will not work like this, you need to set flag inside other swift flags `-D DEBUG` then it will work. You can get more details about build configuration flags [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run time

```
NSDictionary* env = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];

if ([[env valueForKey:@"debugger"] isEqual:@"true"]) {
    NSLog(@"debugger yes");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"debugger no");
}
```

Compile time

```
#ifdef DEBUG

// Something to log your sensitive data here

#else

// 

#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to add the "debugger" environment variable yourself.